# Get information of Active Directory object using LDAP path

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, win32com

How to get all attributes and values of an Active Directory object using LDAP path with win32com package ?
Example:

```py
import win32com.client


ldap_path = "LDAP://CN=aaa,DC=bbb,DC=ccc,DC=eee"

ldap_object = win32com.client.GetObject(ldap_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

My own answer:

```py
import win32com.client


def get_attributes_and_values(ldap_path):
    ldap_object = win32com.client.GetObject(ldap_path)
    ldap_object.GetInfo()

    attributes = [
        ldap_object.Item(x).Name
        for x in range(0, ldap_object.PropertyCount)
    ]
    for attribute in attributes:
        value = getattr(ldap_object, attribute)
        yield {attribute: value}


ldap_path = "LDAP://CN=aaa,DC=bbb,DC=ccc,DC=eee"

attr_val = get_attributes_and_values(ldap_path)
for x in attr_val:
    print(x)
```

`Item`, `Name`, `PropertyCount` are objects/attributes of "COM" object that has been wrapped by `win32com.client`.